# Wrapping templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, wrapper, member-functions

I am currently trying my hand at developing a small game engine, and I am using EnTT for the ECS and event system. Because all of the EnTT stuff is just implementation stuff, I don't want to have any of it exposed, so I am developing wrappers for all of the stuff I am going to use.

I am currently trying to wrap the event dispatcher in my own class. Here's how the EnTT event dispatcher is used (from their [wiki](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/wiki/Crash-Course:-events,-signals-and-everything-in-between)):

```cpp
struct an_event { int value; };
struct another_event {};

struct listener {
    void receive(const an_event &) { /* ... */ }
    void method(const another_event &) { /* ... */ }
};

// ...

listener listener;
dispatcher.sink<an_event>().connect<&listener::receive>(listener);
dispatcher.sink<another_event>().connect<&listener::method>(listener);
```

Seems pretty simple, so I tried to do this to wrap just that line up:

```cpp
template<typename E, typename L>
void EventManager::subscribe(L listener) {
    dispatcher.sink<E>().connect<&L::receive>(listener);
}
```

And that didn't work, I got this error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘void (handler::*)(const TestEvent1&)’ to binary ‘operator<’
```

However, I didn't give it much thought, because I wanted to be able to have more than one handler per class anyway, so then I tried to find a way to also pass the handler function itself as a template argument:

```cpp
template<typename E, typename L, void(L::*callback)(const E&)>
void EventManager::subscribe(L listener) {
    dispatcher.sink<E>().connect<callback>(listener);
}
```

And I got the same result. After this, I tried numerous ways of doing this, and none of them were able to even compile. I even tried wrapping just the `connect` function by itself, and that didn't work either in any way.

Is this approach even possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: why templates in the first place? why not an abstract base class for event

Comment: @pm100 I have a base class for the event, but that's not how EnTT works. I need to pass it the specific class of the event so it knows who is listening to what. If I just pass the base class, every listener will listen for all the events, which is not very useful